# How to correctly indent text when using `put` in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation, copy-paste, paste, auto-indent

I'm having trouble when `putting` text in Vim. 
Say I want to paste my `/* Comment */` line below the `$('table').append` line...

```
/* Comment */

for (var i=1; i<=lineLength ; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    for (var j=1; j<=lineLength; j++) {
    $('table tr:nth-last-child(1)').append('<td></td>');
    }
}
```

In most text editors, my workflow would be

1. Select `/* Comment */`, hit cut.
2. Move cursor to end of first line of code and hit return.
3. Text editor auto-indents, and I just hit paste.

i.e.

```
/* Comment */

for (var i=1; i<=lineLength ; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    | <==Pipe is position of cursor before paste; pasted lines are inserted here.
    for (var j=1; j<=lineLength; j++) {
    $('table tr:nth-last-child(1)').append('<td></td>');
    }
}
```

But with vim, it seems like I have to do this:

1. Move to `/* Comment */` line, hit `dd`.
2. Move to `$('table').append` line, hit `p`.

New code:

```
for (var i=1; i<=lineLength ; i++) {
        $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
/* Comment */. <== Comment is not correctly indented.
        for (var j=1; j<=lineLength; j++) {
        $('table tr:nth-last-child(1)').append('<td></td>');
        }
    }
```

3. Manually fix incorrectly indented code.

Vim auto-indents fine when I start a new line with `o`, so it seems like it should also handle `putting` onto a new line.... Is there a command that will let me `put` new lines of code with the correct indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:nnoremap p p`[v`]=
```

taken from https://github.com/sickill/vim-pasta.

Comment: How about ``:nnoremap p p`[v`]=``? from https://github.com/sickill/vim-pasta. Or you can try that plugin.

Comment: That code seems to work, thanks. I'll just test it in a few different formats....

Answer (score 5):

You can use `]p` and `[p` to paste at the current line's indention level. Note this only works if the register's content is line-wise. See `:h ]p`

If you want to use `]p` and friends, but always want it to be linewise then I suggest you look at Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin. It also provides `>p`/`<p` mapping which paste one indention level deeper/shallower, as well as `=p`/`=P` which pastes and then re-indents, similar to `p=']`.

Answer (score 0):

`:nnoremap p p=']` does the same as other answer but less keystrokes.  No need to visually select.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant solution is to use `Ctrl-R"` in Insert mode. It puts the content of the register `"` (which stores the most recent deleted text) at the position of the cursor.